# Crop text using ellipsis on a variable length element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a rather awkward layout, where two pieces of variable length text are shown next to each other inside a fixed width container.

Both pieces of text should be left aligned, but if the combined widths fill their container, the left element should start to overflow (and hide the text with ellipsis).

```css
.a0 {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.a1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 100%;
}

.a2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #888;
}

.b0 {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.b1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.b2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<h3>Using Flex (Desired effect for long text)</h3>
<div class="a0">
  <div class="a1">Short text</div>
  <div class="a2">(Always Visible)</div>
</div>

<div class="a0">
  <div class="a1">Long text Long text Long text Long text </div>
  <div class="a2">(Always Visible)</div>
</div>

<h3>Using Inline block (Desired effect for short text)</h3>
<div class="b0">
  <div class="b1">Short text</div>
  <div class="b2">(Always Visible)</div>
</div>

<div class="b0">
  <div class="b1">Long text Long text Long text Long text </div>
  <div class="b2">(Always Visible)</div>
</div>
```

I'm struggling to get the overflow effect while still having the right text left align when the combined width is less than the container.

Does anyone know any way to achieve this effect with a single set of styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `width: 100%` from your flex implementation (`.a1` class).

```css
.a0 {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.a1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.a2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #888;
}

.b0 {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.b1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.b2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<h3>Using Flex (Desired effect for long text)</h3>
<div class="a0">
  <div class="a1">Short text</div>
  <div class="a2">(Always Visible)</div>
</div>

<div class="a0">
  <div class="a1">Long text Long text Long text Long text </div>
  <div class="a2">(Always Visible)</div>
</div>

<h3>Using Inline block (Desired effect for short text)</h3>
<div class="b0">
  <div class="b1">Short text</div>
  <div class="b2">(Always Visible)</div>
</div>

<div class="b0">
  <div class="b1">Long text Long text Long text Long text </div>
  <div class="b2">(Always Visible)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed that, long day I guess, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set width auto in a1 class.

```
.a1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: auto;
}
```